# Is there a way to disable iOS widgets on macOS

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, widget

In macOS Sonoma iOS widgets are shown. My app has a iOS version with widgets and a macOS version with widgets. Is it possible to disable the iOS widgets for macOS Sonoma?

Thx, this is my code:

```
@main
struct favorieteRadiostations: Widget {
    
    let kind: String = "favorieteRadiostations"

    private var supportedFamilies: [WidgetFamily] {
          
        return [.systemSmall, .systemMedium, .systemLarge]
        
    }
    
    var body: some WidgetConfiguration {
                                                
        if #available(iOSApplicationExtension 17.0, *) {
           
            IntentConfiguration(kind: kind, intent: ConfigurationIntent.self, provider: Provider()) { entry in
                
                favorieteRadiostationsEntryView(entry: entry).background(entry.kleur)
                
            }
            
            .configurationDisplayName("Favoriete, recent afgespeelde of extra radiostations")
            .description("Start je favoriete, recent afgespeeld of extra radiostation vanuit deze widget. Pas de widget aan van favorieten, recent afgespeelde of extra radiostations door lang op de widget te drukken en dan te kiezen voor 'Wijzig widget'.")
            .supportedFamilies(supportedFamilies)
            .disfavoredLocations([.iPhoneWidgetsOnMac], for: supportedFamilies)
            
        } else {
           
            IntentConfiguration(kind: kind, intent: ConfigurationIntent.self, provider: Provider()) { entry in
                
                favorieteRadiostationsEntryView(entry: entry).background(entry.kleur)
                
            }
            
            .configurationDisplayName("Favoriete, recent afgespeelde of extra radiostations")
            .description("Start je favoriete, recent afgespeeld of extra radiostation vanuit deze widget. Pas de widget aan van favorieten, recent afgespeelde of extra radiostations door lang op de widget te drukken en dan te kiezen voor 'Wijzig widget'.")
            .supportedFamilies(supportedFamilies)
            
        }
    
    }
        
}
```

I get the following error:
Branches have mismatching types 'some WidgetConfiguration' (result of 'Self.disfavoredLocations(_:for:)') and 'some WidgetConfiguration' (result of 'Self.supportedFamilies')

the error is thrown at this part:

.disfavoredLocations([.iPhoneWidgetsOnMac], for: supportedFamilies)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by applying the `disfavoredLocations` modifier to your widget.

For example:

```swift
struct ExampleWidget: Widget {
    var body: some WidgetConfiguration {
        return StaticConfiguration(kind: "Example", provider: ExampleTimeline()) { entry in
            EmptyView()
        }
        .configurationDisplayName("Example")
        .supportedFamilies([.systemSmall])
        .disfavoredLocations([.iPhoneWidgetsOnMac], for: [.systemSmall])
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx, I added my changed code but get an error. Can't figure out what's going wrong.

Comment: Instead of just `IntentConfiguration`, you need to have `return IntentConfiguration`.

Comment: Thx Confuseious. You were right. It look me some while to really understand the return thing ;))